# Does Pokerus affect Super Training?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I don't have any infected pokemon, but now that it's been made easier I'm interested in EV training. Is it worth getting my pokemon infected if I'm planning to use Super Training to do the EV training? Does it have any effect?

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted, this is a good question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pokerus does not affect Super Training and nor do any other items. The Super Training gives you a set amount of EVs that can't be changed.
Pokerus does not have any adverse effects and is still useful (it doubles EVs you gain) if you plan to EV train by battling pokemon.

Comment: If it *did* affect Super Training, you'd have an awkward time putting a non-multiple-of-8 EV total in a stat through Super Training, especially if you need non-multiple-of-8 totals in more than 1 stat.